# Datatable.net paging not showing in Angular 7 project

Tags: angular, typescript, datatable, datatables

I am trying to get `Datatables.net` to work in my `Angular 7` project.  The table renders fine, but it does not show sorting on columns, paging buttons etc, here is an image of my table missing the above mentioned:

[image: Table]

Here is my project specifications:

- Angular CLI version 7
- Bootstrap-4.3.1

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51363693/using-full-featured-datatables-plugin-with-angular-6) article, and although it referes to `Angular 6`, I am assuming process should be similiar.

Here is my scripts/styles within the `angular.json`file.

[image: Dependencies]

I am setting the DataTable options as follow within my `.ts` class:

```
dtOptions: DataTables.Settings = {
    pagingType: 'full_numbers',
    pageLength: 20,
    paging: true
};
```

And then binding the above options to my `table` as follow:

```
<table datatable [hidden]="!hasData" [dtOptions]="dtOptions" [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger".
```

I do not have any console errors, so finding out what is wrong is quite difficult.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you provide stackblitz?

Comment: Have you tried it with more items than the page length? With four items it seems reasonable that page controls wouldn't be shown.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have yes.  But even with only four items in the table, I should still see the "Showing x to y of z entries".

Comment: @PrashantPimpale Busy with a stackblitz

Comment: please try removing the `dtTrigger`

Comment: @ahmeticat I have actually solved this yesterday, by in fact, removing the dtTrigger.  Not sure why this caused problems.

Comment: Do you use Metronic Angular theme?

Comment: @ahmeticat Using the default theme